# Is there any way to retry failed selenium test in ide (firefox plugin)

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

I need to automate the selenium tests using Selenium IDE. For now everything is working smoothly. I was able to make conditions on the bases of variables using a flow control plugin for Firefox. A couple of times selenium IDE tests fail because of unstable internet, timing etc.

I need to retry a test if its got failed. 
Is there any way to retry the failed selenium test from Selenium IDE?

Comment: You want to ask if there is any way to trigger a selenium IDE test that has failed in its first attempt?

Comment: use try catch inside for loop and store failed URL in somekind of URL and test it again with another method like when your main method finishes, try those URLs which have failed.